# How does the review ban work?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

When one makes too many incorrect reviews, one gets banned from reviewing for a period of time.

I believe that this is valid and correct action. However I am a curious person and I am interested to know what is the mechanism of the ban. In particular I would like to know:

- How many incorrect reviews trigger the ban?
- Do you get banned faster for several incorrect reviews in the streak?
- Do correct reviews improve the total sum?
- Does the formula change after you have banned once? I have noticed that after the ban period expires it is enough to make only one incorrect review to get banned again.
- What is the worst case scenario? I know you first get banned for 24 hours, then for a week. Is there a bottom line?

Comment: Your just seeking this information, this is more of a meta StackExchange question

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't know either ;p